# How to range the dates in a datepicker from code side

Tags: c#

```
         int indextemp = WebUtility.Cast(ViewState["expid_details"], WebUtility.Cast(ViewState["exid"], -1));

        if (indextemp < 0)
            indextemp = URLMessage.GetParam("index", -1);

        ebl.Fetch(ds, indextemp);

        hdnStartDate.Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["nStartDate"].ToString();
        hdnEndDate.Value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["nEndDate"].ToString();


        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "0", "$('#" + txtDate.ClientID + "').datepicker({ " +
            "startDate: $('#" + hdnStartDate.ClientID+ "').val(), " +
            "endDate: $('#" + hdnEndDate.ClientID + "').val() });", true);
```

Kindly see my code,as I want to limit the datepicker between the startdate and enddate contained in the hiddenfields,I want to enable the dates contained in the hdnStartDate and hdnEndDate and disable the rest.Please help

Comment: You can put the function to limit the datepicker range in a js function, instead of registering a client script. That is a bit safer way, and will allow you to debug easily as well.

Comment: I initially tried that,but I am facing a problem with the updatepanel then.